# Gtk.SelectionMode.MULTIPLE allows selection of only one row in Gtk.TreeView

Tags: 13.04, application-development, quickly, gtk3, python3

I'm developing an application using Quickly. I have a Gtk.TreeView with a Gtk.ListStore as its model. The selection mode of the Gtk.SelectionMode is set to Gtk.SelectionMode.MULTIPLE.

The problem is that the Gtk.SelectionMode does not behave as it should:

- Only one row can be selected at a time.
- Impossible to select multiple rows using the Ctrl or Shift key.
- Once a row is selected, it can't be deselected using the Ctrl key.
- Nothing happens when I press the arrow keys.

The problem can be easily reproduced by creating a new Ubuntu application using Quickly (or you can download a test application below).

```
$ quickly create ubuntu-application test
$ cd test
$ quickly design
```

Create a TreeView with a ListStore as its model. Set the mode of the GtkTreeSelection to 'Multiple'. Add some columns and values to the ListStore. Add some TreeViewColumns with CellRendererTexts to the Treeview.

```
$ quickly run -v
```

Note you can't select multiple rows.

Some things I've already tried, but did not change anything:

- Setting the selection mode in the code.

  `self.ui.selection.set_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.MULTIPLE)`

  or

  `self.ui.treeview.get_selection().set_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.MULTIPLE)`
- Moving the GtkTreeSelection `<child>` below the GtkTreeViewColumn `<child>` in the UI file.
- Deleting the GtkTreeSelection from the UI file and setting the selection with

  `self.ui.treeview.get_selection().set_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.MULTIPLE)`

Am I overlooking something obvious? Or could this be a bug?

On a side note, if you set the selection to 'Single', it's also not possible to deselect the row.

**EDIT**

If you'd like to help me out, you can download a test application <strike>here</strike> instead of creating a new project with Quickly on your own. Please note you need Quickly to run it.

```
$ cd test
$ quickly run
```

I've implemented some callbacks for testing purposes in test/test/TestWindow.py. You can find the UI definition in test/data/ui/TestWindow.ui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my own problem.

The [`'can-focus'`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget--can-focus) property of the Gtk.TreeView is set to `False` by default. Setting this to `True` fixes the strange selection behavior, as well as other strange behavior that might occur, like not being able to resize a column while its `'resizable'` property is set to `True`.

Answer (score 2):

I can't give a full answer, but wanted to share it. If asking a programming question, always include a minimal working example so others can quickly (ha, pun intended) run and test in your code. I will have to install Quickly, create a Quickly project and change code just to see what your question is about and try to fix it, which I won't.

That being said, here is a minimal working example which behaves correctly, so my guess is Quickly does some magic somewhere which overrides this behaviour.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class TestWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

        ls = Gtk.ListStore(str)
        ls.append(["Testrow 1"])
        ls.append(["Testrow 2"])
        ls.append(["Testrow 3"])
        tv = Gtk.TreeView(ls)
        tr = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        col = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Testcolumn", tr, text=0)
        tv.append_column(col)
        sel = tv.get_selection()
        sel.set_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.MULTIPLE)

        self.add(tv)
        self.show_all()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = TestWindow()
    Gtk.main()
```

Note that you are using an incorrect treeselection mode in your question, the correct one is `Gtk.SelectionMode.MULTIPLE`.

Comment: My mistake, thanks for pointing that out. I've corrected the selection mode in the question. In my project I was using the correct one, thankfully. ;-)
I'll create an example project tomorrow and upload it somewhere. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I've updated my question as you advised and provided an example to download.